# How can use itertools to generate all character permutations in a unicode string(Python)

Tags: python-2.7, iterator

I am trying to generate all possible character permutation in a  unicode string

How can I use

```
import  itertools
itertools.permutation
```

for that purpose ?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't it work straight-forward? `itertools.permutations(mystring)`

Comment: <itertools.permutations object at 0x36e45f0>

Comment: This is the correct result. The `itertools` functions return generators over which one can iterate. See the answer below for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list of the permutations, you can do

```
list(itertools.permutations(mystring))
```

and then you can index it.  This may not be what you need; it's not memory-efficient because it stores the entire list in memory, so you can end up storing a really big list with a small `mystring`.  If you only need to iterate over it **one time**, you should use a loop to iterate over `itertools.permutations(mystring)`.

```
for permutation in itertools.permutations(mystring):
    # do whatever you want to do with each permutation.
```

`itertools.permutations` returns a **generator**, which only gives up values one-at-a-time.  It's way more memory efficient, and if you only need each value once, it's the way to go.

#### How big would the list be?

If you are making a list out of `itertools.permutations`, it get's really big really fast.  The length of the new list will be `len(mystring)!` (that's *factorial*), and the size of each element of the list will be `len(mystring)`.  So the memory complexity is something like `O(n*n!)`, where n is the length of the input string.

On my computer (32-bit Python), I can't do `list(itertools.permutations(mystring))` for  strings longer than 10 characters–I get a MemoryError.  When I try it with a string of length 11, e.g. `list(itertools.permutations('abcdefghij'))`, it tries to store a list with 39,916,800 elements.  Apparently that's too much for me.

Comment: @karu Hahaha, sorry to hear that!  My apologies.

Comment: @karu I've updated my answer to explain _why_ it gets so big so fast, if you're interested.